# Does the length of a viewstate key affect the size of viewstate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, viewstate

It was suggested that the size of the keys being used in ViewState would cause a performance issue as the size of the view state would be larger and therefore increase the page size thus increasing rendering.

While I can see this being the case that the larger key may result in an increase in the view state size I am not so sure the impact is that significant.

As an example does `ViewState["MySpecialProperty"]` result in a larger ViewState than `ViewState["x"]`? And if it does, is the difference really significant enough to be a concern in a standard web app.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703956/c-sharp-does-performance-degrade-if-i-use-a-large-viewstate-names

Comment: did not find this one before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of viewstate key does affect the size of the viewstate. However it is only minimal. From small tests that I did it on 'MySpecialProperty' vs 'x' the difference by 20 or so characters. Also not that it could add up if you had more lengthy keys.

However you should focus on the values stored in the viewstate instead of the keys, since this will consume much more space.

Some references:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101888/ViewState-Various-ways-to-reduce-performance-overh

Comment: Thanks for the link. Definitely gives me some options.

Answer (score 1):

> As an example does ViewState["MySpecialProperty"] result in a larger ViewState than ViewState["x"]?

Yes, the resulting `ViewState` would be larger as key/value pairs get encoded.

> Is the difference really significant enough to be a concern in a standard web app?

IMO, no. I'd worry more about how many pairs you put into `ViewState` and whether you actually need to pass that information on to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, it affects the size of the ViewState, as you mention it is not significant if you only add one variable to the ViewState, **on the other hand, if you start writing variables like `x`, reading the code will be a pain, so it's better to have a balance favoring the readability of the code**

Before considering things like this to improve performance, create some load tests and base on the results take the right decision.

Performance of ASPX pages is something really important, [take a look to the 8 seconds rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_performance#8-second_rule)

However you could try to improve performance related with the ViewState in other ways, basically, disable ViewState for controls that do not need it

For more information:

http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/ASP.NET_2.0_Performance_Guidelines_-_View_State

Comment: On the point of code readability, that is also one of my concerns. Server-side we setup constants to get around that.

Comment: Remember this: **Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live.** [Check this out - not recommended for ppl with heart problems =(](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/coding-for-violent-psychopaths.html)

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the horses mouth: [msdn viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

> ...The view state of a page is, by default, placed in a hidden form field named __VIEWSTATE. This hidden form field can easily get very large, on the order of tens of kilobytes. Not only does the __VIEWSTATE form field cause slower downloads, but, whenever the user posts back the Web page, the contents of this hidden form field must be posted back in the HTTP request, thereby lengthening the request time, as well...
>
> **The Cost of View State**
>
> Nothing comes for free, and view state is no exception. The ASP.NET
>   view state imposes two performance hits whenever an ASP.NET Web page
>   is requested:
>
> 1. On all page visits, during the save view state stage the Page class gathers the collective view state for all of the controls in its
>      control hierarchy and serializes the state to a base-64 encoded
>      string. (This is the string that is emitted in the hidden __VIEWSTATE
>      form filed.) Similarly, on postbacks, the load view state stage needs
>      to deserialize the persisted view state data, and update the pertinent
>      controls in the control hierarchy.
> 2. The __VIEWSTATE hidden form field adds extra size to the Web page that the client must download. For some view state-heavy pages, this
>      can be tens of kilobytes of data, which can require several extra
>      seconds (or minutes!) for modem users to download. Also, when posting
>      back, the __VIEWSTATE form field must be sent back to the Web server
>      in the HTTP POST headers, thereby increasing the postback request
>      time.
>
> If you are designing a Web site that is commonly accessed by users
>   coming over a modem connection, you should be particularly concerned
>   with the bloat the view state might add to a page. Fortunately, there
>   are a number of techniques that can be employed to reduce view state
>   size. We'll first see how to selectively indicate whether or not a
>   server control should save its view state. If a control's state does
>   not need to be persisted across postbacks, we can turn off view state
>   tracking for that control, thereby saving the extra bytes that would
>   otherwise have been added by that control. Following that, we'll
>   examine how to remove the view state from the page's hidden form
>   fields altogether, storing the view state instead on the Web server's
>   file system.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx):

> By default, view state data is stored in the page in a hidden field
>   and is encoded using base64 encoding. In addition, a hash of the view
>   state data is created from the data by using a machine authentication
>   code (MAC) key. The hash value is added to the encoded view state data
>   and the resulting string is stored in the page.

So calculating byte by byte, yes your view state would be longer when you use a longer key for your entry because more characters should be converted to base64. but this is never is a big concern because the size of the key compared to the size of the data length is (usually) very small.